# I get an error, Memory error occured, (e.g. segmentation error, memory limit Exceed, stack overflow,... etc)

Tags: python, memory

I have seen many solutions for stack overflow, but, my code isn't large (less than 256MB combined static and heap memory, less than 1MB stack memory). so, I don't know why the issue happened.

```
T=int(input())
max = 0
min = 0
a=[]
cnt = 0
i=0
for test_case in range(1,T+1):
   T2=int(input())
   the_value = input().split()
   for test_case2 in range(1, len(the_value)+1):
      if max < int(the_value[cnt]) :
          max = int(the_value[cnt])
      cnt+=1

cnt=0
min = max
for test_case2 in range(1, len(the_value)+1):
    if min > int(the_value[cnt]) :
        min = int(the_value[cnt])
    cnt+=1
i+=1
print('#{}{}'.format(i,max-min))
```

This code is to find the maximum and minimum in the input number and get the subtraction.

Error

> (Runtime error)  Error Message:  Memory error occured, (e.g.
>   segmentation error, memory limit Exceed, stack   overflow,... etc)

Comment: Would you paste the exact error. That would be more helpful.

Comment: Add more details about the error! Thank you

Comment: are you using Jython?

Comment: @황인규 that is not the actual error message... Please copy and paste the text that is printed.

Comment: @InAFlash Yes, it is

Comment: @MatteoItalia That's all. There was no problem when I tested it with pycharm, but there was a problem in the coding site. Could my code not run because of memory limitations?

Comment: @황인규 argh that's not really helpful on part of that site; still, yes, that's entirely possible.

Comment: @황인규, can you give the inputs you are giving to it. also the expected behaviour of the code